# Can I get an array as an output using apply function on a matrix?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, apply, sapply, mapply

I have the below R function

```
testfun<- function(x)if(sum(x)>15){array(1:8,rep(2,3))} else{ array(8:1,rep(2,3))}
```

I apply this function on each row of a matrix  as shown below

```
apply(matrix(1:9,nr=3),1,testfun)
```

I am getting output as

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    8    8    1
[2,]    7    7    2
[3,]    6    6    3
[4,]    5    5    4
[5,]    4    4    5
[6,]    3    3    6
[7,]    2    2    7
[8,]    1    1    8
```

But I want the output to be a multidimensional array. something similar to -

```
, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    8    6
[2,]    7    5

, , 2, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    2
[2,]    3    1

, , 1, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    8    6
[2,]    7    5

, , 2, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    2
[2,]    3    1

, , 1, 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2, 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

Can I do this in R without having to define any function on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with `apply`. You can get the desired output using `vapply`, like this:

```
M <- matrix(1:9, nr=3)
vapply(1:nrow(M), function(i) testfun(M[i,]), FUN.VALUE = array(0,rep(2,3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `replicate`

```
replicate(3, testfun())
```

Comment: Yes. I oversimplified the  problem statement. In actual code the output of the testfun is a complex transformation to the input to testfun and not a constant array for all inputs. I will edit my question accrodingly